# Export MobaXterm sessions with or whithout credentials

Tags: windows, mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm Professional Edition v22.1 Build 4888 (windows).
I have a lot of saved sessions inside MobaXterm, a lot of them with saved credentials.
How can I export sessions without saved credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do the following:

1. Export the sessions.
2. Edit the file with notepad++ and do a find-and-replace with nothing for the user in question, this way when other users import the sessions they won't have my user specified by default.